# i want to create a css curved shape line and add the breakpoint and in the breakpoint when i click i want to open a model with show basic details

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

i want to draw this type of line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bandwidth Line</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bandwidth-line">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i want to create this type of bandwidth type line in css or react js when i click on the breakpoint i want to open the model with the information like name, age etc.

[image]

so here is my question

Comment: Not sure what you mean by cSS curved shape. What have you tried? If you create your line as an image then you can place the breakpoints at positions relative to the image using %offsets.